# Algorithm for simple 2D top down vehicle collision physics?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to create a simplified GTA 2 clone to learn. I'm onto vehicle collisions / physics. The basic idea I would say is to apply force F determined by vehicle A's position and velocity onto point P on vehicle B. But what should that do exactly? My vehicles have a center position and an angle, but I'm not sure what something like apply force should do. How could I determine the new center and angle of the vehicle after the hit?

It doesn't have to be realistic, just something that would get the job done.

Thanks

Comment: Are you already familiar with conservation of momentum?  Or are you looking for guidance on how to apply it?

Comment: @Andrew Durward I'm looking for guidance on how to apply it.

Comment: You should ask this in the physics site. And then convert that into an algorithm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 2d you need to make your algorithm satisfy the triangle inequality.

Comment: @Milo:Is my answer helpful?